# Bind ng-model to checkbox as well as colorpicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using bootstrap-colorpicker angular js plugin. I want ng-model value transparent if checkbox is checked otherwise color picker value. This is the code.

```
{
.
.
'color':'transparent'
.
.
}
<button colorpicker type='button' ng-model='col.color'>Choose Color</button>
<input type='checkbox' ng-checked='value=transparent'/>
```

I want that ng-model value become transparent if checkbox is checked, otherwise the value returned by colorpicker. Secondly I am using default value as transparent, so any idea how can I check checkbox by default.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is this:

- HTML

  ```
  <button colorpicker type='button' ng-model='col.color'>Choose Color</button>
  <input type='checkbox' ng-model='useTransparent' ng-change="setActualColor(useTransparent)" /> {{actualColor}}
  ```
- Controller

  ```
  $scope.actualColor = 'transparent';
  $scope.useTransparent = true;
  $scope.setActualColor = function (useTransparent) {
      $scope.actualColor = useTransparent ? 'transparent' : $scope.col.color;
  }
  ```

In the future, consider carefully searching the angular documentation, the [checkbox documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked#!) is pretty good and understandable.